# My Script Multiplying An Array Key Value Does't Work

Tags: php, arrays, math

H there - firs time posting here - I will spare letting you know that I'm "new to PHP and Perl", as that will become painfully obvious below.

Below is a script I wrote to scrape a bank's asset amount, multiply it by 3% and display the results. I explain my flow idea below, and show the result I am getting compared to what I should be getting. My guess is that I can't do math with a value that is still inside an array. Is there an implode process I'm missing before I can start doing some math.

The URL I'm scraping is on my server so run at will.

```
<?php  

// scrape page content of credit union
$dataassets = file_get_contents('http://ablistings.com/boise-project.htm');

// define regular expression to grab credit union's assets amount
$regexassets = '/members,\s(.+?)\smillion/';

// run the preg_match
preg_match($regexassets,$dataassets,$matchassets);

// print the second key of the array [1] which is just the numerical value (in this case $214.4)
$assetsamount = print_r($matchassets[1]);

// add 3% to the value of $214.4, so first we multiple .03 by value
$three_percent_increase = ($assetsamount * .03); // should egual 6.432

// now add the percentage to the orginal asset amount - in this case 6.432 + 214.4 which = 220.832
$final_sum = ($three_percent_increase + $assetsamount);

echo $final_sum;
// sum should be $220.832 but the sum this script produces is $214.41.03 

?>
```

Comment: Use `var_dump` at various places in your script and check every value is what you expect it to be.

Comment: Does `$assetsamount` really begin with `$`? You can't do arithmetic on that.

Comment: Wow - that was FAST. I'll carry out both of these suggestions and report back. Thanks much for your help!

Comment: Barmar - I think you have sent me down the right path already. I need to do math with the value of $assetsamount. I'm confused for sure because I have done math before like this; $value1 = ($value2 * $value3); print $value1;

Comment: Where is the Perl question...?

Comment: Isn't that a Perl expression in the regex statement?

Comment: Perl regex is different from Perl code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$dataassets = 'members, $214.40 million';
// define regular expression to grab credit union's assets amount
$regexassets = '/members,\s\$([\d.]+?)\smillion/';

// run the preg_match
preg_match($regexassets,$dataassets,$matchassets);

// print the second key of the array [1] which is just the numerical value (in this case $214.4)
$assetsamount = $matchassets[1];

var_dump($assetsamount);
// add 3% to the value of $214.4, so first we multiple .03 by value
$three_percent_increase = ($assetsamount * .03); // should egual 6.432
var_dump($three_percent_increase);
// now add the percentage to the orginal asset amount - in this case 6.432 + 214.4 which = 220.832
$final_sum = ($three_percent_increase + $assetsamount);

echo $final_sum;
```

There were 2 problems with your code:

1. You're not skipping over the `$` in the original amount. I've modified the regular expression to do this.
2. You were assigning the result of `print_r` to `$assetsamount`. `print_r` doesn't return the value it prints, it just returns `1`. So it was adding 3% to 1, resulting in `1.03`.

When it printed `$214.41.03`, it was actually two things: `214.4` was from `print_r($matchassets[1])`, `1.03` was from `echo $final_sum`.

Comment: Thanks Barmar - amazing - so where is your Paypal email so I can send you a booya ;-)